# C# - What's the opposite of "IsNullOrWhiteSpace"?

Tags: c#

I am using an if condition with "IsNullOrWhiteSpace(+textbox)" to refer to a text filed that has no value or whitespace only. However, now I need to know hot to specify a field that is not empty or whitespace only.

This is the code I wrote:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathofsrcfilesTOCOPY.Text))
```

But what if I want to specify to have the command run only when the textfield is NOT null or empty?

Thank you very much for any help. I am a beginner. Help is appreciated.

Have a great day!

Comment: `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathofsrcfilesTOCOPY.Text)`?

Comment: @lhoworko Thank you very much! I'm not a developer but I had to create a small tool, I somewhat failed to find this small info. Have a great day!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` returns true if the text is null or whitespace. If the return value is `false`, then the text is populated with non-whitespace characters.

Search for where the condition is not true using `!`.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathofsrcfilesTOCOPY.Text))
```

this is the equivalent of:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathofsrcfilesTOCOPY.Text) == false)
```

Both of the above will enter the if statement if `pathofsrcfilesTOCOPY.Text` is populated with non-whitespace text.

Comment: @user16666620 Thank you very much, it helped! I'm an absolute beginner, and for some reason, I failed to find this info myself, yet I had to create a small tool. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

Worth noting, that although the accepted answer is correct, I find it easier to follow, when assigning its result to a variable and then evaluating that variable in the if condition.

```
bool isPathEmpty = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathofsrcfilesTOCOPY.Text);
if (!isPathEmpty) 
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: even better would be (isPathEmpty == false), then you dont have to deal with as much potential for bugs as you would with the ! getting missed between ( and I